# What does next() mean when using NodeJS to write a REST API

Tags: node.js, rest

I'm a newbie to NodeJS and REST and I'm experimenting how to write a simple REST API. I came across with the following segment of code. I understand the meanings of req and res, but I'm not sure about next. Also, is the next in the parameter same as the next() method? 
Hope someone can help me clarify. Thank you.

```
function findAll(req, res , next){
db.productinfo.find(function (err, productinfo) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });
    res.end(JSON.stringify(productinfo));
});
return next();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like Express middleware and `next()` lets the middleware chain continue to the next step.  Because a middleware operation could be async, it does not progress automatically until you call `next()` as passed in as an argument.

Details here: http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: so the next in the parameter bracket is the same thing as calling next(); correct?

Comment: @docommonthingsuncommonly - The `next` in the parameters is a function reference (a pointer to the function).  When you call `next()`, you're calling the function who's reference was passed as the third argument.  In Javascript, functions are objects and can be passed as arguments just like other objects.  To execute such a function, you take its argument name and add `()` to the end of it.